# Como ordenar um array de objetos em JavaScript através de um valor do objeto

Tags: javascript, react

Estou com uma dúvida de como eu posso organizar um array de objetos no JavaScript através da data de criação do item que vem como um valor no objeto, segue um exemplo:

```js
[
  {
    ...valores,
    requestedCase: {
       ...valores,
       creationDate: "2020-02-04T17:18:02"
    }
  },
  {
    ...valores,
    requestedCase: {
       ...valores,
       creationDate: "2020-01-31T13:49:22"
    }
  }
]
```

Quando recebo esse dado da API, eu gostaria de criar um novo array com os itens ordenados de forma **decrescente** através da `creationDate`.

Dei uma pesquisada e não consegui achar algo que resolvesse meu problema, alguém pode me ajudar por favor!

Comment: essa outra tbm é quase a mesma coisa: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/434909/selecionar-itens-e-ordenar-lista-de-objetos

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Como ordenar uma array de objetos com array.sort()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/46600/como-ordenar-uma-array-de-objetos-com-array-sort)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o método `.sort()` convertendo o valor de `creationDate` em objeto de data:

```js
const api = [
  {
    requestedCase: {
       creationDate: "2020-01-31T13:49:22"
    }
  },
  {
    requestedCase: {
       creationDate: "2020-01-31T13:48:02"
    }
  },
  {
    requestedCase: {
       creationDate: "2020-02-04T17:18:02"
    }
  }
];

const decrescente = api.sort(function(a,b){
   return new Date(b.requestedCase.creationDate) - new Date(a.requestedCase.creationDate);
});

console.log(decrescente);
```

Comment: Valeu Sam!!! Funcionou aqui!

Answer (score 3):

Abaixo tem um código demostrativo.

O importante é criar uma função de ordenação, no seu caso:

```
function dataDecrescente(a, b) {
  return a.creationDate < b.creationDate ? 1 : a.creationDate > b.creationDate ? -1 : 0
}
```

Essa será a callback chamada na função `.sort` do array. Talvez seja interessante colocar um `new Date()` com os parâmetros.

Depois disso basta chamar o método de ordenação do seu array passando o callback da seguinte forma:

```
array.sort(dataDecrescente);
```

```js
// função para ordenação
function dataDecrescente(a, b) {
  return a.data < b.data ? 1 : a.data > b.data ? -1 : 0
}
// criar estrutura que será ordenada
let teste = [];
let i = 1;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  teste.push({
    'id': i++,
    'data': new Date().toISOString()
  })
}, 200);
//tempo para que a estrutura seja populada
setTimeout(() => {
  clearInterval(interval); // para a população da estrutura
  console.log(teste.sort(dataDecrescente)); // resposta com a ordenação da estrutura de forma decrescente
}, 5000);
```

Comment: Valeu Lucas!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Experimenta algo desse tipo, ele ordena pela objeto `Date()` , o `slice()` é para desagregar do objeto original:

```
var valores = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var data = [
  {
    ...valores,
    requestedCase: {
       ...valores,
       creationDate: "2020-02-04T17:18:02"
    }
  },
  {
    ...valores,
    requestedCase: {
       ...valores,
       creationDate: "2020-01-31T13:49:22"
    }
  }
];


var result = data.slice().sort((a, b) => new Date(a.requestedCase.creationDate) > new Date(b.requestedCase.creationDate) ? 1 : -1);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Valeu pela ajuda Ivan!!!!